# Java rmi, differentiating between multiple client

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, command-line-interface

Edit: To be clearer, I basically need to differentiate between the different clients doing remote method invocation in objects stored in the server remote object registry. How could I do that?

And here is the situation:

I am currently in the process of creating a client/server command line interface application using Java rmi to exchange data (stored in Strings) between the clients and server.

I'm having problem whereas I must allow a client to send an authentication command with a user/pass. This authentication command (exemple: >user myUserName myPassword) must be sent through the same remotely called method used to send all the other commands for which the server must answer.

My problem : The client must, strictly, only send his commands and display the text result of his command received from the server. As simple a client as it gets, it has no state.

Since some methods requires the client to be logged in or have a different server-side implementation if the client is logged in or not, I need to to keep track of the client logged in state on the server(not a problem, I plan to simply keep a time stamp on each user in the user database and use a timeout) and must also differentiate between different clients.

Now, I think I have a good idea of how remote object works and I've been able to register a remote object on the server side and access a remote method from it using the client.

So, I need to do more, I must not only have client being able to access remote method, I also need the remote method(and the server running them) to know which network client is invoking this method(without passing the client username/pass as parameters in the remote method).

I think the rmiclientsocketfactory and rmiserversocketfactory must be customly used to do this, but I don't know how to proceed.

thanks you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not stored in the registry. Stubs are stored in the registry. The remote objects are in the server host.

See `java.rmi.server.RemoteServer.getClientHost()`.

Socket factories haven nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks you EJP, the getClientHost() method from RemoteServer looks exactly like what I need, I knew threading for different client was done by java RMI itself, but I somehow did not find anything related to that particular method while doing research and I can assure you I looked around a lot. I'll try working forward with this, thx for ur help.

Comment: @tehjord well it's exactly not in the most obvious place ;-)